# Deeplink to a specific Approvals on Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, deep-linking

Is there a way to build a deeplink to a specific Approvals task on Microsoft Teams, based on its ID?

The closest I could get was a deeplink to the Approvals app tab: https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/7c316234-ded0-4f95-8a83-8453d0876592/approvals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the ideal, since it's outside Teams, but I found a way to open a single Approval instance with this link:

`https://flow.microsoft.com/manage/environments/<environment-id>/approvals/received/<approval-id>`

It will open the Approval instance in the Power Automate's Approvals tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can open an app install dialog from your Teams app and also can install the app in other contexts. This is the only deep link you can use for opening an app. Use the following deep link format to open an app install dialog from your Teams:

`https://teams.microsoft.com/l/app/<your-app-id>`

Reference Document-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-link-application?tabs=teamsjs-v2

Comment: I don't want a link to install the app, but a link to open a specific Approvals instance.